# Which characters in Nanatsu no Taizai can read power levels?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

So Hawk was given a magical device by Merlin if I recall correctly, and he can read power levels. Gowther has shown to be able to read Diane and King's power levels, I guess because he's a doll he has some device incorporated and can read them. Is there any other character in Nanatsu no Taizai who can read power levels?